How to read multiple flow files in nifi using groovy script
I have four(it may be ten as well) incoming files,two flow files have the same name(flowfile1.txt) and another flow file names has same name(flowfile2.txt). Now i want to read these flow files based on the flow file name and implement some logic and has to send one flow file to output to the next processor. Could you please help on the, Below is the scenario. Flow file name are same but the content is different
flowfile1.txt
flowfile1.txt

flowfile2.txt
flowfile2.txt

After my logic completes , I have to send the output to the next processor as like below
Flowfile1.txt( I will read both flowfile1.txt and do some logic and will send the output to flowfile1.txt and send to next processor,
will do the same with flowfile2.txt as well..
I just need only how can i read it to the groovy script , i will implement the logic based on my business case.
my flow file has the content as like below
flowfile1.txt
A 300 CT001
A 302 CT003
A 303 CT302
A 304 CT304

And i am getting the content from my database as like below
A 300 CT002
A 301 CT002
A 302 CT003
A 303 CT302
A 304 CT304

My output flow file should be like below
flowfile1.txt(file name should be the same)
R 300 CT001 (since the new flow file has data change in the third column)
D 301 CT002 ( since we have deleted it in the new flow file)
A 304 CT304 (since we have added in the new flow file which is not availbe in the old db fie data)

